# Guava MultiSet vs Map?

Tags: java, guava

My understanding of Multiset is a set with frequency, but I can always use Map to represent the frequency, is there other reason to use Multiset?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Advantages of a `Multiset<E>` over a `Map<E, Integer>`:

- No special code required when adding an element that is not already in the collection.
- Methods for handling the count of elements directly: `count(E)`, `add(E, int)`, etc.
- The intention of the code is clearer. A `Multiset<E>` obviously maps the elements to their counts. A `Map<E, Integer>` could map the elements to arbitrary integers.

See also:

[Multiset Javadoc](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html)

[Multiset explained in the Guava Wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multiset)

Comment: Besides being probably more efficient than your implementation, Multiset makes it clearer what you're actually trying to do, and it's more difficult to screw up.  Typically, with a Map<E, Integer>, you're dealing with a lot of stuff: checking if the key is already in the map, dealing with count zero, and all kinds of tricky business.  Multiset just works.

Answer (score 9):

To me, the most important point that sets `Multiset` apart from a `Map` is that it's a `Collection`: you just put stuff into it and you can get counts later. It conceptually fits the use cases for which it's designed where a `Map` does not. For those use cases, a `Map` is just a hack that kinda-sorta works OK since Java didn't provide anything more appropriate.