# Finding number of occurrences of char from a short List/Array in a infinitely large List/Array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have been working on a practical situation wherein I require an algorithm, have made a generic problem out of that. Considering there are are Two Arrays :-

Source[10] = {'a', 'v', 'l', 'r', 'p', 's', 'x', 'd', 'q', 'o' , 'g', 'm'}

Target[N] = {'a', 'v', 'l', 'r', 'p', 's', 'x', 'd', 'q', 'o' , 'g', 'm',a', 'v', 'l', 'r', 'p',a', 'v', 'l', 'r', 'p',a',

'v', 'l', 'r', 'p',a', 'v', 'l', 'r', 'p',a', 'v', 'l', 'r', 'p',a', 'v', 'l', 'r', 'p',a', 'v', 'l', 'r', 'p',a', 'v',

'l', 'r', 'p',a', 'v', 'l', 'r', 'p', .... }

We need to have an efficient algorithm to find the frequency of occurrences of characters from Source in Target.

I have thought of hashing the complete Target list and then iterate through the Source and do the lookup in the hashed list. Can people comment/validate the approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your character set is reasonably limited, you can use character codes as indexes into an array of counts. Let's say you have 16-bit characters. You can do this:

```
int[] counts = new int[65536];
foreach (char c in Target)
    counts[c]++;
```

With the array of `counts` in hand, you can easily find the frequency by looking up a code from the `Source` in the `counts` array.

This solution is asymptotically as fast as it could possibly get, but it may not be the most memory-efficient one.

Comment: Just to add on, I believe that this is the asymptotically fastest way possible. You _could_ change target to a data structure which would allow counting to go faster. However, the change itself is likely to be no faster than O(n) since all n elements in target would have to be placed in the new data structure.

Comment: This surely helps!!! Its much simpler and O(n) works... I was thinking of hashing the list and then thought of lookup... but that would have been costly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a hashed list is, so I can't comment on that. For efficiency, I would suggest turning the target array into a multiset. [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) has a nice implementation of such a thing (although the Java Collections Framework does not). So does [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/Bag.html) (where it's called a `Bag`). You can then simply iterate through the source and look up the frequency of each element in the multiset. As described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860770/guava-multiset-vs-map), using a multiset is easier than using a `HashMap` from elements to frequencies, although it does require using a third-party library.